# Edit Record Type in Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, record-type

I have a custom object and inside that there is this standard field named  **Record type**. It is a picklist. There are 4 options in the picklist and by default it is set to **Drop Ship Purchase Order**. I want to change that to **Internal Purchase order**.  I don't see any picklist option here.
[image: See this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default record type is defined per profile. So for each profile you want you use, go to the object settings for the object and choose the "Default Record Type".

For example:

[image: screen shot of default record type selection in a profile]

Comment: **1st question:**: where is this object setting located ? I could not find anywhere in my object page. **2nd question:** So u mean if i am logged in and I change it to XYZ and if another person logs in with his credentials he the change won't reflect in his.

Comment: 1) Profiles are listed under Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles. 2) Every User is a assigned to a profile so you only need to set this in as many profiles as you are using (at a minimum 1). You can see the profiles assigned to your users under Setup -> Manage Users -> Users.